# PHP: `strcmp` serialization of identical object and array failing

Tags: php, arrays, object, serialization, strcmp

I have a legacy app where i am trying to migrate changes from the old into the new while generating a log of changes.  Things are going well; however, I keep running into "changes" that change *nothing*.  After digging into this, I found that the legacy code is using arrays and the new code is using objects.  If serialized, I thought they would be identical.  After all, if they are dumped via `print_r` they are identical.  But that is not the case.  Even more astounding, the objects *keep* their integer keys even after serialize-unserialize cycling them.

The request is: how can I show these two strings are identical since their resulting object/array is identical save for key typing.

```
<?php
  $v3v = 'a:2:{s:9:"lastindex";s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"1";}';
  $v4v = 'a:2:{s:9:"lastindex";i:1;i:1;s:1:"1";}';
  $v3 = unserialize($v3v);
  $v4 = unserialize($v4v);
  die('<pre>'.print_r($v3,true).' '.print_r($v4,true));
```

**outputs (the identical):**

`Array
(
    [lastindex] => 1
    [1] => 1
)
 Array
(
    [lastindex] => 1
    [1] => 1
)`

**so let's now bring them "back to life":**

```
$v3v = serialize($v3);
$v4v = serialize($v4);
die('<pre>'.print_r($v3v,true).PHP_EOL.print_r($v4v,true));
```

**whaaa? how did you remember your integer keys??"**

```
a:2:{s:9:"lastindex";s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"1";}
a:2:{s:9:"lastindex";i:1;i:1;s:1:"1";}
```

**and how can i get you to stop???**

Comment: Difference is in `s:1` and `i:1`. In first it is `string` and in second it is `integer`

Comment: yes, yes, i realized the `strcmp` was failing for the exact thing you are pointing out.  the question is, since in the application both serialized values produce the same output, how can we recognize in this instance that these two constructs are identical save for typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_diff` instead of `strcmp`. You can try this -

```
  $v3v = 'a:2:{s:9:"lastindex";s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"1";}';
  $v4v = 'a:2:{s:9:"lastindex";i:1;i:1;s:1:"1";}';
  $v3 = unserialize($v3v);
  $v4 = unserialize($v4v);
  echo empty(array_diff($v3, $v4)) ? 'Identical' : 'Not Identical';
```

`array_diff($v3, $v4)` will return empty `array` if they are indentical.

[Working code](https://eval.in/739210)